# Can I pass an array type before "... " ? Where can I find the macro code for va_*

Tags: c, variadic-functions

1. I read the man page about va_start and get this:

   > The argument last is the name of the last argument before the variable argument list, that is, the last argument of which  the  calling  function knows the type.
   >
   > Because  the  address of this argument may be used in the va_start() macro, 
   >   *it should not be declared as a register variable, or as a function or
   >      an array type.*

   I tried this code and it works well, but it just makes me confused.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdarg.h> 

   void va_func(int i[3],...);
   int main()
   {
         int m[3] = {0,1,2};
         va_func(m,4,5,5,6);
         return  0;
    }

    void va_func(int m[5],...)// I pass a array type here before the "..."
    {
         int i,j;
         va_list ap;
         va_start(ap,m);
         for(i = 0; i < 4 ;i++)
         {
             j = va_arg(ap,int);
             printf("argv[%d] is %d\n",i,j);
         }
         va_end(ap);
    }
   ```
2. Then I want to read the code of those `va_*` macros. But I get nothing from `<stdarg.h>`
   and `<cstdarg>`. Just can any hacker tell me how and where can I learn those `va_*`things?

---

Here is my current problem:

I want write a `Open(const char *path,int oflag, ...);` function. I hope it call  the `open` and do some error test.

```
int Open(const char * path,int oflag, ...)
{
    int rt;
    rt = open(path,oflag,...)// I don't know how to do this now.
    if(rt == -1)
     err_deal_func();
    else
     return rt;
}
```

Comment: The `<stdarg.h>` header for GCC is minimal — in fact, it is non-existent on Mac OS X.  The information is actually built into the compilers directly; including the headers merely make the functionality available.  This is completely permissible by the standard.  Your function with the array is not guaranteed to work; the standard says that `parmN` should not be an array type, but your code uses an array type.  You could use a pointer instead, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C runtime provides no way to know how many arguments were passed. Therefore, it's not possible to forward arguments that easily. Most functions that accept forwarded arguments will accept a `va_list` object (see [`vprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vprintf/#example) for instance).

You need to understand the parameters you were passed to be able to tell how many you received. `printf` is able to do that by reading the format string, and each time it sees a placeholder in the string, it reads the next parameter; but if you feed it an incorrect format string or incorrect parameters, you're going to crash.

This is what `open` does, too:

> The `oflag` argument may indicate that the file is to be created if it does
>   not exist (by specifying the `O_CREAT` flag).  In this case, **open** requires a
>   third argument `mode_t mode`; the file is created with mode mode as described
>   in chmod(2) and modified by the process' umask value (see umask(2)).

That is, it does not seek to read a third parameter if `oflag` doesn't include `O_CREAT`. This is what you would need to do as well, and as you can see, it's slightly gory.

If you're doing C++ (and not just plain old C), I suggest you use function overloads, which has the added benefit of being type-safe (and it's a *huge* benefit):

```
int Open(const char * path,int oflag)
{
    int rt = open(path,oflag);
    if(rt == -1)
     err_deal_func();
    else
     return rt;
}

int Open(const char * path,int oflag,mode_t mode)
{
    int rt = open(path,oflag,mode);
    if(rt == -1)
     err_deal_func();
    else
     return rt;
}
```

If you really need to do this in C (and not C++), you need to use the `oflag` parameter to determine if you need to read the additional parameter.

```
int Open(const char* path, int oflag, ...)
{
    int rt;
    if ((oflag & O_CREAT) == O_CREAT)
    {
        // we have O_CREAT, this means that we were passed 3 arguments
        // declare argument list
        va_list ap;
        // create an argument list starting after the `oflag` argument
        va_start(ap, oflag);
        // read the next argument in `ap` as a `mode_t` variable
        mode_t mode = va_arg(ap, mode_t);
        // there are no more arguments to read, so clean up the list
        va_end(ap);

        // finally, call `open` passing that additional parameter
        rt = open(path, oflag, mode);
    }
    else
        rt = open(path, oflag);

    if (rt == -1)
        err_deal_func();
    else
        return rt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks . I will use the _old c_  anyway.

Comment: Since the `va_` defined in macro , would you tell me where can I read them ?

Comment: @LidongGuo, the macros are implemented with compiler-specific functions. With Clang, `va_start` expands to `__builtin_va_start`, which is a "function" implemented by the compiler. It wouldn't be possible to implement those using C alone, anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter before `...` in a variable argument function is special; the standard calls it `parmN` and it's used to provide information about the number and possibly the type of the variable argument part.

`parmN` will be used by the macro `va_start`, so it can't be omitted:

```
void va_start(va_list ap, parmN);
```

In the case of `open`:

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ... );
```

`oflag` is the special parameter, `open` will check the value of it to determine what it will receive as variable argument part.

For a simple example to start, you can check out [this article](http://c-faq.com/varargs/varargs1.html) in C FAQ.

Comment: Is it just a suggestion to use the paraN? The test code compile without any warning and error , and it works nice.

Comment: @LidongGuo To write a vararg function, no, `paraN` is necessary because it will be used by `va_start`.

Comment: I read you link , it is very useful. Since the `va_*` things defined by macro , would you tell me where can I read them?

Comment: @LidongGuo The C11 standard library `stdarg.h`. Or you can read the whole [C FAQ:variable length argument lists](http://c-faq.com/varargs/index.html)

Comment: I don't know why but in `stdarg.h` only include a `cstdarg` ,it again include `<cstdarg>`!

Comment: @LidongGuo I didn't mean reading the source code, read the standard about the library `stdarg.h`, like C11 7.16

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have a parameter of array type in C/C++:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to
>   ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, ... (C99 standard, 6.7.5.3 paragraph 7)

The `i` and `m` in your code both have type `int *`.

Neither is it possible to have a parameter of function type in C/C++:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be
>   adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’, ... (C99 standard,
>   6.7.5.3 paragraph 8)

Therefore, the statements about parameter of function or array types in the documentation for `va_start` seem to be completely pointless.